# Calculating the date and time difference in libre office calc returns #VALUE

Tags: date, time, format, libreoffice-calc

In libre office calc I got two cells with the following content:

2022.01.10 15:51:06

2022.01.10 16:14:22

When I substract one from the other I get #VALUE!

Both cells are formatted like this "JJJJ.MM.TT HH:MM:SS"

I tried different formats and also changing the format of the output cell, but I could not get it to work.

I want the difference in hours if possible.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Press Ctrl+F8 or choose View-Value Highlighting. Which color of date cells you see? Blue? Of black?

Comment: The source data is black. The outcome cell is green.

Comment: Black - this is NOT date, this is text. Try select cell (Shift-Click) and choose Data-Text To Column, choose data type as "Date (YMD)". Repeat for second cell. Color must be blue and you will get diff between dates instead #VALUE!

Comment: For values from your example you will get 00:23:16. To convert this value to hours just multiply it to 24 and get 0.387777777777778 hrs

Comment: Thanks, the formula is working now!
Unfortunately this converts the source cell to "10.01.22 15:51".
I want it to stay the same.
Also I am pasting new values every day and would be happy if all new data is directly formatted correctly, so that I don't have to do the reformatting everytime.
Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: @electricar I would recommend creating a new question for this follow up.